# Javascript Object comparision

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript object

```
myData={my_ID: "NSOfe",his_ID: "AuJ"}
```

I would like to compare `my_Data` and see whether or not I have same `my_ID` in the following javascript objects (`myData_1`). If there is, it will return true on the console.

```
myData1=[{my_ID: "NSOfe",his_ID: "suJ"},{my_ID: "NSOfew",his_ID: "kuJ"},{my_ID: "NSOfey",his_ID: "BuJ"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then compare the `my_ID` attributes for the objects:

```
console.log(myData.my_ID === myData1.my_ID); // true
```

For many comparisons place your items into an array and use a for loop to go through them:

```
var dataArray = [ myData1, myData2, myData3 ];

for( var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++ )
    console.log(myData.my_ID === dataArray[i].my_ID);
```

Comment: @ilyasUyanik Then place your objects in an array and go through them comparing them to `myData`. I've updated my answer to reflex that.

Answer (score 0):

You can stringify the array and then simply do an indexOf call on it like so:

```
var myData=[{my_ID: "NSOfe",his_ID: "AuJ"},{my_ID: "NSOfe",his_ID: "AuJ"}];

var myDataString  = JSON.stringify(myData);

console.log(myDataString.indexOf('"my_ID":"NSOfe"') !== -1);
console.log(myDataString.indexOf('"my_ID":"NSOfe2"') !== -1);
```

Console ouput:

```
true
false
```

Comment: This doesn't work properly. JSON can only represent a small subset of JavaScript objects. e.g. dates, regular expressions and functions are not supported. Other than that, for large objects it's extremely inefficient, and your `-1` check only checks if that particular string is anywhere in the object. This problem can be solved easily by just inspecting the object.

Comment: @Tiddo, It works very properly for the original question

Comment: Although it technically, by accident, works for the exact situation proposed in the original question, it cannot be extended for any other similar question and it will fail as soon as there is only a slight change to the code. E.g. as soon as nested objects come into play it won't work. But more importantly, it's just a very bad way to do it. There's a trivial, proper solution to this problem, and string comparison is not it. "It works" is not a good enough motivation for a solution.

Comment: @Tiddo, I don't want to talk to you no more, you empty headed animal
food trough whopper! I fart in your general direction! You mother was
a hamster and your father smelt of elderberries!